# Selecting floating point numbers in decimal form

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, psql, to-char

I've a small number in a PostgreSQL table:

```
test=# CREATE TABLE test (r real);
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO test VALUES (0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009);
INSERT 0 1
```

When I run the following query it returns the number as `8.96831e-44`:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM test;
      r      
-------------
 8.96831e-44
(1 row)
```

How can I show the value in `psql` in its decimal form (`0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009`) instead of the scientific notation? I'd be happy with `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000896831` too. Unfortunately I can't change the table and I don't really care about loss of precision.

(I've played with [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html) for a while with no success.)

Comment: Ah, saw that iti is a real. It is a floating point representation... You will never get the value back: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @ppeterka66: it's `real` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: Updated my answer: this seems to be a known issue, and something I don't feel right about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Real in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html) is a floating point datatype, stored on 4 bytes, that is 32 bits.

Your value,

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
```

Can not be precisely represented in a 32bit IEEE754 floating point number. You can check the exact values [in this calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html)

<del>You cold try and use **double precision** (64bits) to store it, according to the calculator, that seems to be an exact representation.</del> **NOT TRUE** Patricia showed that it was just the calculator rounding the value, even though explicitly asking it not to... Double would mean a bit more precision, but still no exact value, as this number is not representable using finite number of binary digits. (Thanks, Patricia, a lesson learnt (again): don't believe what you see on the Intertubez)

Under normal circumstances, you should use a NUMERIC(precision, scale) format, that would store the number precisely to get back the correct value.

**However**, your value to store seems to have a scale larger than postgres allows (which seems to be 30) for exact decimal represenations. If you don't want to do calculations, just store them (which would not be a very common situation, I admit), you could try storing them as strings... (but this is ugly...)

**EDIT**

This to_char problem seems to be a **[known bug](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201109201717.p8KHHlZU087195@wwwmaster.postgresql.org)**...

Quote:

> My immediate reaction to that is that float8 values don't have 57 digits
>   of precision.  If you are expecting that format string to do something
>   useful you should be applying it to a numeric column not a double
>   precision one.
>
> It's possible that we can kluge things to make this particular case work
>   like you are expecting, but there are always going to be similar-looking
>   cases that can't work because the precision just isn't there.
>
> In a quick look at the code, the reason you just get "0." is that it's
>   rounding off after 15 digits to ensure it doesn't print garbage.  Maybe
>   it could be a bit smarter for cases where the value is very much smaller
>   than 1, but it wouldn't be a simple change.

([from here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11125.1316540968@sss.pgh.pa.us))

However, I find this not defendable. IMHO a double (IEEE754 64bit floating point to be exact) will always have ~15 *significant decimal digits*, if the value fits into the type...

#### Recommended reading:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [Postgres numeric types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-numeric.html)
- [BUG #6217: to_char() gives incorrect output for very small float values](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201109201717.p8KHHlZU087195@wwwmaster.postgresql.org)

Comment: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009 does not have an exact representation as a finite length binary expansion, and therefore cannot possibly be exactly represented by a double. The closest double is 8.999999999999999701371399759001187751098450398312665851146155700922553097223778373253413973215499304719454149066593107164635512162931263446807861328125E-44. It may "seem to be" exact because of rounding.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan you're right... Holy crap, my trusted IEEE754 calculator does round even when I set it not to round the value... I hate moments like this...

Comment: The trick I use to get exact values of doubles is to write a program in Java that constructs a BigDecimal with the double's value and prints that. The double-to-BigDecimal conversion is exact, and BigDecimal's toString produces all the digits it has.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The sad thing is I know that - I've been recently quite deeply involved in the intricacies of how that works, and how Double.toString operates, and yet with the yellow warning light on in my head about the finiteness of the binary representation, I decided to believe what I saw, and go ahead writing something totally off...