# postgresql round division

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to divide values and round them up to 8 decimal places but i found that some divisions return in **scientific notation**.

How can i always get round division without scientific notation?

- `select round( 123/100000000::decimal, 8 )`

  returns `0.00000123` as expected.
- `select round( 1/100000000::decimal, 8 )`

  returns `1e-8` but... i was expecting `0.00000001`

How can i round 1/100000000 to 8 decimal places and return **0.00000001** ?

sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1534

Thanks for help.
best,

Comment: I think the default scale is 6.  Try using something like `decimal (18, 8)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, don't work too. see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1534

Comment: `1e-8` and `0.00000001` are the same thing, aren't they?

Comment: What client application are you using? Exact PostgreSQL version (from `SELECT version()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, when I try your code in Postgres 9.3.4 using pgAdmin, both return the values you want. The values are *not* in exponential notation. Hence, I suspect this is an issue with your application, not the database.

An easy way to check is to put the value as a string:

```
select round( 1/100000000::decimal, 8 )::text
```

This should *not* return exponential notation.

Comment: you are right, casting as text returns value not in exponential/scientific notation.
For just displaying value (instead of calculations) this is what i need.

Here goes updated sqlfiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1550

Answer (score 0):

Probably second case go beyond precision range 8.

You can check this Question [Selecting floating point numbers in decimal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869321/selecting-floating-point-numbers-in-decimal-form)

Also what version are you working with because in pgAdmin 9.2 I get a different result

[image]

Comment: postgresql v9.4.. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1534